# select2 multiselect ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm try to fill my multiple select2 using ajax, but i don't have return on field.

That's my HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="instituicaoSel" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen" value="">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#instituicaoSel').select2(
{
    placeholder: "Escolha uma ou mais instituições",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    width: '100%',
    multiple: true,
    ajax: {
        url: basepath + "perfil/buscarInstituicoes",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
            q: term, 
            page_limit: 10,
            page: page 
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page)
        {
            var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
            return { results: data.results, more: more };
        },
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
    }
});
```

And that is my result on ajax:

```
[{"result":[{"id":"1","text":"Ag\u00eancia Brasileira de Desenvolvimento Industrial"}],"total":1}]
```

The value that I put on placeholder don't is shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="sel" placeholder="MyPlaceHolder">
  <option></option>
  <option>Option value</option>
</select>
```

you need add `<option></option>`

an example http://hromnik.com/web/select2/

and the solution : http://hromnik.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/select2-placeholder-does-not-work-solution/

Comment: But i need fill my field with ajax, and just the input hidden have this option, if you have an example using <select type="multiple"> populating with ajax, that's works for me.

Comment: you can drawing it? a wireframe or anything of the select... how you want

Comment: I need a multiple select(Using tag input or select) that I can pass data using ajax, just this.